# How to execute entire SQL file in PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use Node and the SQL library [ts-postgres](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-postgres) for Node to execute SQL statements. For my unit-tests and deployment I prepared an entire SQL file which describes the layout and format of my database.

`ts-postgres` addresses this in the documentation with the following:

> The query command accepts a single query only. If you need to send
> multiple queries, just call the method multiple times. For example, to
> send an update command in a transaction:
>
> ```
> client.query('begin');
> client.query('update ...');
> await client.query('commit');
> ```

But in my case I have a very long complex `*.sql` file I would like to execute instead. It would be difficult to split this into individual commands. It has also statements like stdin involvement below, which is not covered by any of the API functionality.

```sql
COPY public.favorite (user_id, project_id) FROM stdin;
9   1
9   2
9   3
\.
```

Any ideas what I could do instead?

Comment: That `copy` syntax is specific to `psql` you will need to use `psql` to run it

Comment: Does that mean I couldn't execute this through such an API?

Comment: Yes, you cannot do that. You'd have to separate the `COPY` command and its data and use the `COPY` API. it would be easier to call `psql` to process the dump file.